# How to find WITH RECOMPILE metadata in SQL Server (2005)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, metadata

How do you find which SPs are declared WITH RECOMPILE, either in INFORMATION_SCHEMA, sys.objects or some other metadata?

(I'm adding some code to my system health monitoring and want to warn on ones which are declared that way where it is not justifiable.)

**Note: I'm not looking for general text search for 'WITH RECOMPILE' - I can already do that, but it will give false positive for any commented or literal versions of the text.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [GSquared](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/UserInfo480409.aspx) on [SQL Server Central Forums](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic634987-338-1.aspx), I found it, there is a flag called `is_recompiled` in `sys.sql_modules`.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty way I would use:

```
SELECT
     o.name
FROM
     syscomments c
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON
     o.object_id = c.id
WHERE
     c.text LIKE '%WITH RECOMPILE%'
```

That's probably not a good idea for use in an actual application though. If I have a few minutes I'll try to dig up a cleaner way. The above will also catch procs that have that string commented out, it uses the MS SQL Server specific table syscomments, etc.

Comment: Right - I can do that, but without parsing the code and ensuring it's not in a comment or a literal...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query I use which will search user defined views, stored procedures and functions for any given search string:

```
DECLARE @strSearch varchar(50)
SELECT @strSearch = 'my search string'

SELECT
    so.[Name],
    OBJECT_ID(so.[Name])    
FROM
    [sysobjects] so
JOIN
    syscomments sc
ON
    sc.[ID] = OBJECT_ID(so.[Name])
WHERE 
    (so.[xtype] = 'FN' OR so.[xtype] = 'P' OR so.[xtype] = 'V') AND
    so.[category] = 0 AND
    sc.encrypted = 0 AND
    sc.[text] like '%' + @strSearch + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have something for general search - mine uses a CTE and gives individual lines (for multiple occurrences) and a snippet of code around the occurrence.